# Pass data back using protocols and delegates

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates, console, protocols

I have two view controllers: GameFavorites pushes SelectFavorites, and all I want to do is show on NSLog that I am passing data back once I am in SelectFavorites with a button. Here is my code:

SelectFavorites.h

```
@class SelectFavorites;
@protocol SelectFavoritesDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)addItemViewController:(SelectFavorites *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:    (NSString *)item;
@end


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GameFavorites.h"

@interface SelectFavorites : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SelectFavoritesDelegate> delegate;
- (IBAction)button1:(UIButton *)sender;
@end
```

SelectFavorites.m

```
#import "SelectFavorites.h"
#import "GameFavorites.h"



@interface SelectFavorites ()


@end

@implementation SelectFavorites

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)button1:(UIButton *)sender {

NSString *itemToPassBack = @"Pass this value back to Gamefavorites";
[self.delegate addItemViewController:self didFinishEnteringItem:itemToPassBack];


}

@end
```

GameFavorites.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SelectFavorites.h"

@interface GameFavorites : UITableViewController <SelectFavoritesDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

GameFavorites.m

```
#import "GameFavorites.h"

@interface GameFavorites ()

@end

@implementation GameFavorites


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {


    SelectFavorites *selectFavorites = [[SelectFavorites alloc]   initWithNibName:@"SelectFavorites" bundle:nil];
    selectFavorites.delegate = self;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:selectFavorites animated:YES];

    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}



//view did load is called when your view is actually presented onscreen
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (void)addItemViewController:(SelectFavorites *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSString *)item
{

NSLog(@"This was returned from ViewControllerB %@",item);


}
```

Shouldn't my string show in the console when I hit the button? I have no errors it runs fine, but nothing in the console.

A few thoughts:

- The pushing viewcontroller is a tableview controller, but I don’t think it should matter.
- Maybe my init method or viewDidLoad methods need to be edited but not sure where.

Comment: Try to set the delegate property as `assign` instead of `weak` in SelectFavorites.h

Comment: And also check whether the IBAction button1 is actually called in the first place when you tap the button

Comment: Changed the delegate property to assign, and added an NSLog under my button to make sure it is getting called. No luck.

Comment: Is your button1 action called in the first place when you tap the button?

Comment: Yeah I added an NSLog under my button 1 to see if it was being called and it showed in the console.

Comment: So not sure whats going on...